# Sampling with index-omitting-condition

Tags: r

Is it possible to sample a vector but skip specific indices?

```
expl <- c("This","is","an","example","One","Two","Three")
skipIdx <- c(1, 4)
```

sample such that "*This*" and "*example*" always are on their original positions *1* and *4*.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
weirdsamp <- function(vec, skip) {vec2<-numeric(length(vec))
                           vec2[skip] <- vec[skip]
                           vec2[ -skip]<- sample(vec[-skip])
                           vec2}

> weirdsamp(expl, skipIdx)
[1] "This"    "One"     "is"      "example" "an"      "Two"     "Three"  
> weirdsamp(expl, skipIdx)
[1] "This"    "is"      "Three"   "example" "an"      "Two"     "One"    
> weirdsamp(expl, skipIdx)
[1] "This"    "an"      "is"      "example" "Two"     "Three"   "One"
```

I decided this could be shortened considerably:

```
weirdsamp <- function(vec, skip) { vec[ -skip]<- sample(vec[-skip]); vec}
```

Comment: weirdsamp, it is!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just sample the non-skipped indices.

Set up example:

```
expl <- c("This","is","an","example","One","Two","Three")
skipIdx <- c(1, 4)
```

Now sample:

```
nonskip <- seq_along(expl)[-skipIdx]  ## indices to sample
expl2 <- expl                         ## copy
set.seed(101)                         ## for reproducibility
expl2[nonskip] <- expl2[sample(nonskip)]
expl2
## [1] "This"    "an"      "Three"   "example" "One"     "is"      "Two"
```